# Libcurl: can't connect to Django development server

Tags: c, connection, libcurl

My C application needs to connect to an Http server and get a response, and I'm having some trouble connecting to a server that isn't running on port 80.

I'm using the Django development server on port 8000 instead of Apache in my development environment.  But I did just test connecting to my Django page on Apache on port 80, and libcurl was able to connect.  I can connect to port 8000 in my browser, but libcurl cannot.

I've tried this url: `http://192.168.1.186:8000/mypage/` and `http://192.168.1.186/mypage/` and then setting CURLOPT_PORT to 8000 but neither have worked.

The specific error is

```
libcurl error: 7
libcurl error: couldn't connect to server
```

The server is running CentOS 5.5, and I do have port 8000 forwarded through iptables and SELinux is disabled.

I'll just include the relevant code.

```
char* url = "http://192.168.1.186:8000/mypage/";
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wait_for_response);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Also using command line curl doesn't work either.
`curl http://192.168.1.186:8000/mypage/`

Edit: I've discovered that if I switch Apache to port 8000 curl works fine, so there is something in the Django server that is ignoring my requests.

Comment: Can you: `telnet 192.168.1.186 8000` ? If that fails too, it's a network/firewall/configuration issue, not a programming/curl issue.

Comment: I get connection refused.  I updated the question because I discovered that curl works fine when Apache is on 8000.  So the Django server is just ignoring my curl requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it figured out.

I was using this command to start the server
`python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.186:8000`

But for some reason you have to use 0.0.0.0:8000 instead.
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

I don't know why that works, but it does.